# Ruby performance tuning

Tags: ruby

I've an application runs on k8s that uses ruby v2.7.4, I'm tryning to have a look on some environment variables that may enhance the performance of my application. Can you help me to understand the below parameters and how to calculate the right value ?

```
WEB_CONCURRENCY
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_MAX
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Most are Garbage Collection Settings

Just don't. Unless you have very specific problems around garbage collection or odd memory constraints because you're running an embedded system, you shouldn't have to worry about garbage collection at all, especially on newer Rubies. You can find most of the values you're looking for in [GC#stat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/GC.html#method-c-stat), but I have no idea where you're getting "WEB_CONCURRENCY" from. That one is likely tied to your web server rather than Ruby's GC module or any known Ruby environment variable, so you're going to have to figure that one out some other way.

If you're having trouble with memory usage in Ruby, the problem is most often tied to objects that never go out of scope and therefore never get garbage collected. There are many better ways to optimize most Ruby applications than messing around with GC settings, but if you *do* have a valid use case, the [GC module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/GC.html) is where you should start.

Comment: `WEB_CONCURRENCY` is a puma config specifying the number of workers to run. A rule of thumb is having a `WEB_CONCURRENCY` of double your COU cores. but each worker consumes memory therefore it depends highly on your application and the server's specs what value might make sense. See this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) in the Heroku docs.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, please can someone tell me what is dyno size ?